# Do I need to create my own nginx.conf file to run this docker-composer.yml file succesfully?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config, nextcloud

I am trying to get a nextcloud + mariadb + nginx docker-compose up and running locally, but I am stuck when it comes to the nginx.conf file. I am following [this guide at the base-fpm section](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud). Here is the docker-compose.yml file, what I ran in my CLI and the error i got:

```yaml
version: '2'
volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypw
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypw
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
  app:
    image: nextcloud:fpm
    restart: always
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypw
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
  web:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    volumes_from:
      - app
```

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "nextcloud_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "nextcloud_nextcloud" with default driver
Creating volume "nextcloud_db" with default driver
Creating nextcloud_db_1 ... done
Creating nextcloud_app_1 ... done
Creating nextcloud_web_1 ... error

ERROR: for nextcloud_web_1  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init 
caused: rootfs_linux.go:59: mounting "/home/nowak/docker/nextcloud/nginx.conf" to rootfs at 
"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4869db7f0302ec8b7e5f4328b861e64627daa78728d443913052cecd1cd095a9/merge
d/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" caused: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory 
onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: 
starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: 
rootfs_linux.go:59: mounting "/home/nowak/docker/nextcloud/nginx.conf" to rootfs at 
"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4869db7f0302ec8b7e5f4328b861e64627daa78728d443913052cecd1cd095a9/merge
d/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" caused: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory 
onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Do I need to create a nginx.conf file and place it in my work directory?
The guide does mention this:

> The configuration for nginx is stored in the configuration file nginx.conf, that is mounted into the container. An example can be found in the examples section [here](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/tree/master/.examples).

But when I follow that link, I can't seem to find any example of nginx.conf files.

Comment: I've found at least one nginx.conf file in the repo you linked: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/master/.examples/docker-compose/with-nginx-proxy/mariadb/fpm/web/nginx.conf

Comment: @OlivierKrull That was exactly what I needed! I looked in the wrong places :( Thanks!

Comment: I was also looking in all the wrong places - and your comment helped me @GetterJetter - want to make it an answer if you care for the internet points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like other people are also searching for the file, so I'll add the link from my comment to the right file here:

https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/master/.examples/docker-compose/with-nginx-proxy/mariadb/fpm/web/nginx.conf